# How to download multiple files from the Firebase Storage Console?

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage, firebase-console

I have an images directory in Firebase Storage and I am trying to download all the files in that directory from the console. It gives me the option to select all files and a download button appears but when I click it only 1 image is downloaded.

Is there a way to download all the images via the Firebase Console?

Comment: Hmm.... that sounds like a bug to me. Can you [file a bug report](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/)?

Comment: Sure, just sent it.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [gsutil](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil) tool to download all files from your Firebase Storage bucket. Use the [cp](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/cp) command:

```
gsutil -m cp -r gs://{{bucket_url}} {{local_path_to_save_downloads}}
```

`-m` performs a multi-threaded download. Use this if you want to download a large number of files to perform parallel downloads

`-r` to copy an entire directory tree

Answer (score 1):

Just had the same issue. Turns out it's a known issue.

Here's the response from Firebase support:

> This is a known bug when trying to download directly on the Storage
>   Console. Our engineers are working on getting it fixed, however I
>   can't provide any timelines right now. We apologize for the
>   inconvenience this may have caused you. For the time being, you may
>   download the file by right-clicking the image previewed, then choose
>   "Save image as...".